# GQL/Alternatives to retrieve data from Many to Many relationship

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I haven't been able to find a good simple tutorial on how to query many to many relationship model using GQL or any alternative. Can anyone give me an example with Python using GQL or any alternative?

EDIT:

```
results = RestaurantReview.all().filter("Restaurant = %s", restaurant_key).filter("User = %s", user[0].key().__str__()).fetch()
```

The error log of following reflects above statement:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group':
```

Is this related to DB List Property? If so, can you give example on this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant GQL or any alternatives to retrieve data from many to many relationship. I've edited my question.

Comment: for your information [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) is a very solid example on how to represent many to many relationships in BigTable. The concept is you have a filed which is a list property and you hold there all the keys of the entity you want to relate with. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @Chris-Top..Will give a try..;)

Comment: The error message is a non-sequitir - there's no mention of 'group' anywhere in your statement. Please include the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ManyToManyModel.all().filter("model1 =", model1_key).filter("model2 =", model2_key).fetch()`

ManyToManyModel is a model with two properties, both reference properties, `model1` and `model2`. `model1_key` and `model2_key` are each a single key for their respective fields. For more in-depth information, see [this helpful article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) in the documentation.

Comment: I've tried that and can you please checkout and help on my latest edited question ?